# Trigger SuiteScript on workflow button NetSuite

Tags: javascript, button, workflow, netsuite

I need to add a button to my sales order form where when you click the button it will trigger a script I created. Basically the button calculates and fills in fields based on what you put for earlier fields. Could I add a button through a workflow and link this script through the add button option?

I also have no clue how to test this out on the sales order form I'm not even sure it works. Any advice would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button using a Before Load using event.  You can also 'attach' a undeployed client side script during this event.

You client side script will contain the logic you need when the button is clicked.

You code will be like this:

```
function beforeLoad_addButton(type, form) {
     form.setScript('customscript_so_logic'); // This should be the script id of your undeployed client side script
     form.addButton('custpage_custom_button', 'Custom Button', logicFunction); // logicFunction should be a function in your JS file.
}
```

Basically when the user clicks on your Custom Button, it will execute the logic found in 'logicFunction'

Comment: You can alternatively create a "Workflow Action" script that can be accessed in any workflow.

Comment: So I tried the .addButton method but when I try to run I get ReferenceError: "vsoeValidate" is not defined. (VSOEUserEvent.js$321576#21) - vsoeValidate is the client side function I am calling on. I have that function saved in a client script in netsuite

Comment: Can you post the code edits you did?  Also can you provide a screenshot of the client side script you have in NetSuite?

Comment: eXtreme, you can add a workflow state, this is where your workflow button will transistion to when clicked. In the workflow state, you can put in a custom workflow action script, like erictgrubaugh suggested.